# Unit testing classes that use EPPlus

Tags: c#, unit-testing, export-to-excel, epplus

I am having issues unit testing classes that use EPPlus. In my mind, I have two options.

I can mock & inject the HttpPostedFileBase into a method, or I can mock & inject the EPPlus ExcelPackage class.

Mocking the HttpPostedFileBase, at least doing a true mock, seems limited. I can mock the basic properties on the file (MIME type, filename, etc), but to mock its InputStream in a way that allows the tests to actually interact with it, seems extremely difficult. The only solution I can come up with is to provide a real excel file, create a real FileStream with it, and assign that FileStream to my mock HttpPostedFileBase's InputStream. But then it's technically an integration test, not a unit test.

```
const string FakeFileName = "TestExcelFile.xlsx"; // path to an actual excel file
var fileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open);
var fakeFile = A.Fake<HttpPostedFileBase>();
A.CallTo(() => fakeFile.InputStream).Returns(fileStream);
```

I figured if I wanted to do an actual unit test, I could mock and inject the EPPlus ExcelPackage class instead. I could then mock the related Worksheet, Columns & Cell classes, setting their properties dynamically to fit the conditions of my test, while never touching a real file. The problem is, most of the EPPlus classes are sealed, so I can't mock them with FakeItEasy. I tried creating wrapper classes for them (see below), so I could mock the wrapper class instead... but some of the classes I need to mock/wrap have internal constructors, so I can't instantiate them. (I did try getting around the internal constructor problem using a couple of ugly hacks, but didn't have success.) And so I've hit a wall with this option.

I am still a novice and have a lot to learn. Perhaps my concept of a wrapper class is incorrect, and I am doing it wrong. Is there a way around this I can't see, or should I just give up, use a real excel file, and call it an integration test? So far, that's what I am leaning towards.

```
public class ExcelWorksheetsWrapper : IEnumerable<ExcelWorksheet>
{
    public readonly ExcelWorksheets _excelWorksheets;

    public ExcelWorksheetsWrapper()
    {
        // internal constructor, can't instantiate
        _excelWorksheets = new ExcelWorksheets();       
    }

    public ExcelWorksheet Add(string worksheetName)
    {
        return _excelWorksheets.Add(worksheetName);
    }

    public IEnumerator<ExcelWorksheet> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _excelWorksheets.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _excelWorksheets.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking a third-party library is often a pain in the neck and creates cryptic unit tests.

Each test should be short, easy to read and understandable. It should be easy looking at the test to understand what the intended successful operation should be.

It's usually better to create wrapper classes around third-party libraries, and use interfaces on those classes. You can then create mock objects that implement those interfaces just for testing.

Still, that is easier said then done. Obviously there are going to be things that third-party libraries do that can't just be cut-out of code and make for meaningful tests.

In those cases, you still should use your own interfaces, but isolate those kinds of unit tests to just the bare minimum that are dependent upon the third-party library.

Try taking a look at the SOLID programming pattern. Systems built using that pattern are often easier to test because everything is loosely coupled.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: Thanks for the info. What you said is what I am already trying to do though - I am already trying to use wrapper classes (and I didn't show in the example for brevity's sake, but my real wrapper classes do have interfaces). The problem is writing those wrapper classes. I don't know how to write them without eventually calling the class I am wrapping - and I can't do that if I can't instantiate it. As this is my first experience with wrapper classes I may be doing it wrong however.

Comment: @EF0 I had a problem testing webclient. How could I test my code without using webclient? The number of wrapper classes and things I had to reinvent would be a huge waste of time. So instead I created a simple web server on localhost, and tested using that. Sometimes you just have to be creative. Isolating third-party APIs can sometimes produce more work than is worth it.

Comment: So if I am interpreting this correctly, and mocking/isolating third-party APIs as you said is realistically not always worth it, then tests which interact with said third-party API must use its concrete implementation - making those tests integration tests. So in relation to my question, doing an integration test using an actual file - is probably the way to go? Really, whatever I call it, I guess the important thing is that it's tested.

Comment: @EFO you can run tests that use file resources that are isolated to that test and the test folder. That would still be a unit test to me. It becomes an integration test when you can't isolate the class you are testing. The fact that the class uses a third-party API is just an implementation detail of that class. The key here is you need to test your code not theirs. You need your tests to document what the class was intended to do and verify it does it. 99% of the time these issues are not third-party by a design fault blocking you from unit testing just one class.

Comment: Understood. My definition of a true unit test is a little different - but regardless - that is what I am going to do (a file used only by the tests).