# Create Moq for Epplus Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, epplus

My first question here. I have looked my query but could not find a helpful answer.

My task is to write unit test case for my excel file. The issue I am facing is that we using Epplus for excel files and I am not sure how can we write unit test cases for this. I looked up and found that we can also use MOQ to mock up. But again I could not find any helpful links for mocking an excel file that uses Epplus. I found this link [Unit testing classes that use EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703971/unit-testing-classes-that-use-epplus) but I am not sure how I can implement this .

I would appreciate if someone can provide a sample of how to write a simple unit test for the excel file. The test can be to check if file uploaded is an excel file or not, checking if the excel is empty or not etc.

Sorry at this moment I dont have any sample. What I can share is the code where I am reading the excel file:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
  [HttpPost("upload")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
  {
   JArray data = new JArray();
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
      ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
      //Check if excel is empty.
      if (worksheet.Dimension == null)
      {
         return BadRequest("File is blank.");
      }
     data = Helper.CreateJson(worksheet);
                }
     return Ok(data);
  }
}
```

I had created a helper class as:

```
public static JArray CreateJson(ExcelWorksheet worksheet)
{
  JArray data = new JArray();
  JObject jobject = new JObject();

  int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
  int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;

    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
    {
       for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
        {
          var value = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value;
          //Excel has 2 columns and I want to create a json from that.
          if (col == 1)              
          {
             jObject.Add("ID", rowValue.ToString());
          }
          else
          {
             jObject.Add("Name", rowValue.ToString());
          }
        }
         data.Add(jObject);
         jObject= new JObject();
     }
   return data;
}
```

This is the Test Class i have so far.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private MyController _controller;
    public TestClass()
    {
      _controller = new MyController (); 
    }

      [Fact]
    public void Upload_WhenCalled()
    {
        //var file = new FileInfo(@"C:\myfile.xlsx");
        //...what next?

        var file = new Mock<IFormFile>();
        var content = File.OpenRead(@"C:\myfile.xlsx");

        var result = _controller.UploadFile(file.Object);
        //When I debug it throws error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    }
}
```

Comment: Mock `IFormFile` to return the file stream in your test and pass that to the action under test. Make sure all other necessary dependencies are satisfied. Finally, assert expected behavior against actual behavior.

Comment: @Nkosi I have updated my code with mocking iform file. But it throws error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." The error is on the my controller in the line: ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(myFile.OpenReadStream())

Comment: Setup the mock to return the stream when invoked. `file.Setup(_ => _.OpenReadStream()).Returns(content);`

Comment: Now while my help should get  you through the current problem, you should really take the advice suggested by @mason about abstracting that tight coupling of `ExcelPackage` out of the controller into its own concern. Would make testing the controller easier. You could always test the wrapper separately as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case mock `IFormFile` to return the file stream in your test and pass that to the action under test. Make sure all other necessary dependencies are satisfied.

```
public class TestClass {
    private MyController _controller;
    public TestClass() {
      _controller = new MyController (); 
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Upload_WhenCalled() {
        //Arrange
        var content = File.OpenRead(@"C:\myfile.xlsx");
        var file = new Mock<IFormFile>();
        file.Setup(_ => _.OpenReadStream()).Returns(content);

        //Act
        var result = _controller.UploadFile(file.Object);

        //Assert
        //...
    }
}
```

Now while this should help get you through the current problem, you should really take the advice suggested by other answers about abstracting that tight coupling of `ExcelPackage` out of the controller into its own concern. Would make unit testing the controller easier in isolation.

You could always do an integration test of the wrapper separately as needed.

A simplified example of an interface abstracted from what is currently in the controller

```
public interface IExcelService {
    Task<JArray> GetDataAsync(Stream stream);
}
```

which would have an implementation that mirrors the code in the controller

```
public class ExcelService: IExcelService {
    public async Task<JArray> GetDataAsync(Stream stream) {
        JArray data = new JArray();
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(stream)) {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            if (worksheet.Dimension != null) {
                data = await Task.Run(() => createJson(worksheet));
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    private JArray createJson(ExcelWorksheet worksheet) {
        JArray data = new JArray();
        int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row count
        for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++) {
            JObject jobject = new JObject();
            for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++) {
                var value = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value;
                //Excel has 2 columns and I want to create a json from that.
                if (col == 1) {
                    jObject.Add("ID", rowValue.ToString());
                } else {
                    jObject.Add("Name", rowValue.ToString());
                }
                data.Add(jObject);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

The controller can now be simplified to follow the [Explicit Dependencies Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private readonly IExcelService excel;
    public MyController(IExcelService excel) {
        this.excel = excel;
    }

    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file) {
        JArray data = await excel.GetDataAsync(myFile.OpenReadStream());
        if(data.Count == 0)
            return BadRequest("File is blank.");
        return Ok(data);
    }
}
```

You would make sure that the interface and implementation are registered with the Dependency Inversion framework in `Startup`

```
services.AddScoped<IExcelService, ExcelService>();
```

So now the controller is only concerned with what it is suppose to do when called at run time. I has no reason to be dealing with implementation concerns

```
public class MyControllerTests {
    [Fact]
    public async Task Upload_WhenCalled() {
        //Arrange
        var content = new MemoryStream();
        var file = new Mock<IFormFile>();
        file.Setup(_ => _.OpenReadStream()).Returns(content);
        var expected = new JArray();
        var service = new Mock<IExcelService>();
        service
            .Setup(_ => _.GetDataAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(expected);

        var controller = new MyController(service.Object);

        //Act
        var result = await controller.UploadFile(file.Object);

        //Assert
        service.Verify(_ => _.GetDataAsync(content));
        //...other assertions like if result is OkContentResult...etc
    }
}
```

To do an integration test that involves an actual file you can test the service

```
public class ExcelServiceTests {
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetData_WhenCalled() {
        //Arrange
        var stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\myfile.xlsx");
        var service = new ExcelService();

        //Act
        var actual = await service.GetDataAsync(stream);

        //Assert
        //...assert the contents of actual data.
    }
}
```

Each concern can now be tested on its own.

Comment: Yes the file loads fine now. Sorry I am not asking to be spoon fed here but can you give me an example how can i take out the excel package to its own interface and class. Because in my controller I am doing all the processing and reading of the uploaded file and then returning the data. You mean that I should move everything to the separate excel class. I would appreciate if you would give me a small example for this.

Comment: Thanks I will try to refactor with this and let you know.

Comment: @karen check latest update. Everything should be self explanatory based on how the code is structured.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mock EPPlus to test. Your focus should be on testing your code, not EPPlus itself. Just like you wouldn't test any other library you consume. So have your code generate an Excel file in memory using EPPlus and return it. Then in your test use EPPlus to verify your assertions about the file.

Here's an example of a pattern to use:

```
public class MyReportGenerator : IReportGenerator
{
    /* implementation here */
}

public interface IReportGenerator
{
    byte[] GenerateMyReport(ReportParameters parameters);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMyReportGenerate()
{
    //arrange
    var parameters = new ReportParameters(/* some values */);
    var reportGenerator = new MyReportGenerator(/* some dependencies */);

    //act
    byte[] resultFile = reportGenerator.GenerateMyReport(parameters);

    //assert
    using(var stream = new MemoryStream(resultFile))
    using(var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
    {
        //now test that it generated properly, such as:
        package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Cells["C6"].GetValue<decimal>().Should().Be(3.14m);
        package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Column(5).Hidden.Should().BeTrue();
    }  
}
```

The example above is using the [Fluent Assertions library](https://fluentassertions.com/), though obviously this isn't necessary.

Comment: thanks for your inputs. See my post as I have added more code. I am doing this in my api. I have also added the test class. How can I call the controller upload method in my test class and pass file. The way you have shown above is you are creating excel in the test method itself. I believe I what I need to do is test my api method. How can I do that. Thanks

Comment: @karen Your controller should not be directly modifying the file. All the EPPlus manipulation to a separate class (MyReportGenerator in my example), then your controller should depend that class by interface (IReportGenerator) in my example. Then you test your controller logic separately from your report generation/modification logic. In my example I created a brand new Excel file, but you can have it take a MemoryStream containing the file. This keeps your report modification logic separate from your web application logic, allowing them to be independently tested.